# How to align and make the solving process more pleasing?

Tags: amsmath, mathematics

I would like to make this presentation more mathematically pleasing - that is, I'd like to align this *working* process so that there is no big difference between the first

```
7\left(\frac 1 2 y\right) + 8y &= 9 \\
```

and second line

```
-7y + 16y &= 18 \\
```

I also thought about using `\iff` but am unsure how to align it properly. I would appreciate any feedback regarding mathematical presentation as well.

```
\textbf{Example 1.} \\
In the following system, first equation has $u_1 = 7$ and \emph{common difference} $d = 1$. Second equation has the \emph{common difference} $d = - 3$ and starts with $u_1 = 6$

\begin{align*}
    7x + 8y &= 9 \\
    6x + 3y &= 0 
\end{align*}

Expressing $ x = - \frac 1 2 &y$ from the second equation and substituting into the first one, we get

\begin{align*}
    7\left(\frac 1 2 y\right) + 8y &= 9 \\
    -7y + 16y &= 18 \\
    9y &= 18 \\
    y &= 2
\end{align*}

From here, we substitute back into second equation and obtain $x = -1$.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use two alignment points instead of one. I also added a second way to cope with the problem that *uses* the values *u*<sub>1</sub> in the two equations. It's a bit pointless to mention those values and never employ them.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
In the following system, the first equation has $u_1 = 7$ and 
\emph{common difference} $d = 1$. The second equation has the \emph{common difference} 
$d = - 3$ and starts with $u_1 = 6$
\begin{align*}
    7x + 8y &= 9 \\
    6x + 3y &= 0 
\end{align*}
Expressing $ x = - \frac{1}{2}y$ from the second equation and substituting 
into the first one, we get
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    7\left(\frac{1}{2}y\right) &+{}& 8y  &= 9 \\
    -7y                        &+{}& 16y &= 18 \\
                               &   & 9y  &= 18 \\
                               &   & y   &= 2
\end{alignat*}
From here, we substitute back into the second equation and obtain $x = -1$. 
\end{example}

\begin{example}
In the following system, the first equation has $u_1 = 7$ and 
\emph{common difference} $d = 1$. The second equation has the \emph{common difference} 
$d = - 3$ and starts with $u_1 = 6$
\begin{align*}
    7x + 8y &= 9 \\
    6x + 3y &= 0 
\end{align*}
Multiplying the first equation by $6$, the second by $7$ and subtracting, we get
\begin{align*}
42x + 48y &= 54 \\
42x + 21y &= 0 \\[1ex]
27y&=54
\end{align*}
hence $y=2$. From here, we substitute back into the second equation and obtain $x=-1$. 
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

I also added a proper environment for examples. Avoid `\frac 1 2 y`. It's difficult to read and can lead to bad output if you start using fractions with larger numerator or denominator: `\frac 11 2` will not yield the expected result, would it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this suggestion befit you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools} 

\begin{document}

\textbf{Example 1.} \\
In the following system, first equation has $u_1 = 7$ and \emph{common difference} $d = 1$. Second equation has the \emph{common difference} $d = - 3$ and starts with $u_1 = 6$

\begin{align*}
    7x + 8y &= 9 \\
    6x + 3y &= 0
\end{align*}

Expressing $ x = - \frac 1 2y$ from the second equation and substituting into the first one, we get

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    7\left(\mfrac 1 2 y\right) & + {} & 8y &= 9 \\[-1.5ex]
    & \Updownarrow &\\[-1ex]
    -7y & +{} & 16y & = 18 \\
  && 9y &= 18 \\
    & & y &= 2
\end{alignat*}

From here, we substitute back into second equation and obtain $x = -1$.

\end{document}
```

[image]